The installation does not start
I am the owner of Surface Pro 6, and I wanted to install Ubuntu.
I created 2 volumes, and did not format them, because I know that Ubuntu has other formats. So we went off topic.
I installed Ubuntu 24.04, thinking that it was a new series. Everything started normally, but at the "Installing the system" stage an error appeared about something with the disk.
I downloaded the 22.04 image from releases.ubuntu.com. Everything was installed (I forgot to say, during the installation I watched a tutorial, because I wanted the cameras, microphones, and touchscreen to work).
Everything seemed to be fine, but when I entered the necessary commands and needed to reboot, Ubuntu no longer boots. I thought, OK, take 3 (yes, 3).
I inserted a flash drive with the 22.04 image, set the priority, turned off Secure Boot, and that's it - it no longer boots (and I also forgot to say, I have Windows as a base).
I tried another flash drive, images - nothing helps, but if you set formatting to NTFS in Rufus, then when loading something tries to start the installation, but can't, nothing happens. And if you do everything by default, then everything just freezes on the logo and that's it.

You mention releases, but no actual specifics. Ubuntu is available in many products; that use different installers, but you've not said what you installed; only releases. You select the installer you'll use by the ISO you select when downloaded; where you only mention the release.  Please be specific with details.  (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop uses ubiquity installer, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses subiquity installer etc..   Also note if you use rufus to reformat ISO (ie. selecting formatting) you must match those parameters to your device; I suggest just clone ISO to install media)

I didn't understand you well, but I understood something. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 desktop versions. I don't understand English well, I use a translator. What do you mean, clone an ISO image?

I don't use rufus to write images, but you can influence the installer when you change formatting/write of the ISO by options you choose, which can HELP or HURT depending on what you do. The clone is a simple write without change of ISO to media (ie. no change with formatting used on the ISO itself used), which I think is called dd mode/write on rufus.. That will allow install on most devices using legacy/BIOS/CSM, uEFI or secure-boot uEFI.  The Desktop detail is key though; add to your question.

I use Google Translate, it may translate incorrectly, as I understand it, you want the characteristics of my tablet, here they are
Surface Pro 6
Intel Core i5-8250U 1.60 GHz (but when connected to the charger, all 3.20 GHz)
Intel UHD Graphics 620
8GB ram DDDR4
SAMSUNG KUS030202M-B000 (256 GB, but for Ubuntu, the 2nd volume is 64 GB, everything else is for Windows 11

Now I tried to make a flash drive in Rufes not in ISO but in DD but if I check the box in Rufes "Check UEFI media during boot" 1. something appears but everything is done but error 23 and when all this is done the keyboard appears in the lower right corner but 0 reaction and nothing happens further did it really write it somewhere and now I can't install Linux?

I entered the necessary commands and needed to reboot, Ubuntu no longer boots -- What were those commands?

Commands from the tutorial
wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/master/pkg/keys/surface.asc 
| gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-surface.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release main" 
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux-surface.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-surface linux-headers-surface libwacom-surface iptsd
sudo apt install linux-surface-secureboot-mok
sudo update-grub
Github url:https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup
